# How to download and install ipa file from myserver.com.. in ipad??

Tags: ipad

I'm creating my own appstore for android and ipad applications. I'm using node.js to run my webservices and mongodb for data storage. Webservices are running in port 8030. Eg: webservice at localhost:8030/webservice1. To put everything in place in my server machine, I'm using xampp server. In httpd.conf file I configured it as

`ProxyPass /getapplication http://localhost:8030/webservice1
ProxyPassReverse /getapplication http://localhost:8030/webservice1`

This webservice will start downloading a application file in device. This works fine for apk files. But in ipad while I try to download a ipa file, Safari is showing error as "Safari cannot download this file"

Usually I give the download path directly as http://myserver.com/myfolder/myapkfile.apk
and for ipad http://myserver.com/myfolder/myipafile.ipa. After going through some links, I changed the link for ipad to

`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://myserver.com/myfolder/myipafile.ipa`
Its showing error as "Cannot connect to myserver.com". What might be the problem?? Can anyone help me sort out what am I missing??

Comment: This is because for ad-hoc OTA iOS distributions, it typically requires a .plist (manifest) file which contains the link to the .ipa and other vital app data. Take a look at how BetaBuilder (Mac app, also source available on Github) and TestFlight do it.

Comment: @Luke ya that gave me the solution for my problem.. I just created a plist file which links to the ipa file.. also followed steps from [link](http://samvermette.com/71) Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Shall I post my comment as the answer, so that you may accept it? Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @Luke ya sure........ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(comment posted as answer:)

This is because for ad-hoc OTA iOS distributions, it typically requires a .plist (manifest) file which contains the link to the .ipa and other vital app data. Take a look at how BetaBuilder (Mac app, also source available on Github) and TestFlight do it.

https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder

https://testflightapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

We would need to install the mime type files in our server.

For IIS, Open IIS Manager. Right click 'Server(local computer)'
Select Properties click 'MIME Types' Click 'New...'

Add the Following MIME Types:

.IPA   - application/octet-stream 
.PLIST -  text/plain.